# Navigation Drawer Using Appcompat v7 - Issues with ?android:attr Tag

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, navigation-drawer

I am using an actionbar and navigation drawer in my project.  Using appcompat v7 and v4.

I have added the appcompat v7 WITH resources.

The following is my textview for the navigation drawer list taken straight from the android sample app found at [Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

The bottom three lines all cause my application to fail, it builds okay, but I get a force close and I am not sure how to solve the problem.  I don't understand why the attributes are not being found, considering I added the appcompat with its resources. Or are they not valid with the appcompat or something?

MinSDK Version is 10 and at which the code fails. Above API 10 the code works fine.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: @vikram - Sorry minSDK version is 10

Comment: @vikram, thanks, and perhaps I am misunderstanding, but I thought the appcompat package v7 with its resources was suppose to solve that?

Comment: I removed my comment because I had overlooked `I have added the appcompat v7 WITH resources`. The issue here is with attribute `activatedBackgroundIndicator`. Both `textAppearanceListItemSmall` and `listPreferredItemHeightSmall` are defined in `appcompat v7`, but `activatedBackgroundIndicator` is not. You can verify this by looking at `sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values\attrs.xml`. `activatedBackgroundIndicator` was added in API 11. This is why the code fails at minsdk=10. And like you said: `Above API 10 the code works fine`.

Comment: By the way, this is the drawable that is used by `activatedBackgroundIndicator`: [Link](http://ge.tt/3c6CRxo/v/0?c). You can try using it directly(place it in res/drawable). I am not sure if this will work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue. As i understand older apis haven't predefined textAppearanceListItemSmall, activatedBackgroundIndicator and listPreferredItemHeightSmall. So if you need you can specify your own values or remove this lines and rely on your luck.

Comment: I thought that's what the appcompat package with all its resources was for??

Comment: @Reafidy I think appcompat is responsible for ActionBar resources, not for "listItem" background, appearance and min height

Comment: @Reafidy Yes it should. But in ald google fashion leaves a lot to be desired. Plus... it is full of bugs. Holoeveryehere library is much much much better and reliable.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the values as defined in the compatibility library: It specifies all except the background, which I have chosen listChoiceBackgroundIndicator, although you might play with others as well.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="?attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"/>
```